# Designing a database with multiple foreign keys in a table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to design a database however i've reached an issue regarding how to ensure the best design. The general idea is to store tweets which either can be associated with a Player, Team or Person. My question is then how i can optimize this since i'm sure it is good Practice to have 3 foreign keys in the `Tweet` table, where where only one of them contain a id?

Player: Is the players of each team

Team: Is the team

Person: people who are not associated with a team, but is posting relevant tweets.

**Player**

```
id
name
image
twitter_user
teamId
```

**Team**

```
id
name
twitter_user
```

**Person**

```
id
name
image
twitter_user
teamId
```

**Tweet**

```
id
created
text
personId
teamId
playerId
```

Comment: twitter_id? what you mean by that

Comment: Well inheritance for person/team/player will set foreign key in tweet as 1 instead of 3 - but u'll to create trigger to use continue id between these 3 sub-tables (so u have to write triggers). I don't know if it's worth to spend time doing all these stuff. But it makes sense in theory.

Comment: not sure i understand the triggers, but i can see the inheritance work